# Error in calling function pointer

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to declare and call function pointer inside different classes but getting error while compilation.
Please refer the codes below.
NOTE: This is not the actual code but just a part of actual code with modified variable and function names.

File A.h

```
typedef bool (A::*add_ptr_Typ)(int a,int b ); 

    class A
    {
        public:
        bool add_func(int a,int b );
        void m_assign();
        add_ptr_Typ   add_ptr; 
    }
```

File A.cpp

```
void A::m_assign()
    {
        add_ptr = & A::add_func;
    }
    bool A::add_func(int a,int b )
    {
       if ((a+b) > 10)
       return true;
       else
       return false;
    }
```

File B.h

```
class B
{
public:
add_ptr_Typ   m_add_ptr; 
bool m_process(A* A_ptr);
}
```

File B.cpp

```
bool B::m_process(A* A_ptr)
{
    m_add_ptr = A_ptr->add_ptr;
    (m_add_ptr)(2,3); //error:must use â.*â or â->*â to call pointer-to-member function 
    (*m_add_ptr)(2,3);//error: invalid use of âunary *â on pointer to member
    (this->m_add_ptr)(2,3);//error: must use â.*â or â->*â to call pointer-to-member function 
    this->m_add_ptr(2,3);//error: pointer to member type bool (A::)(int,int) incompatible with object type B
}
```

I tried calling the function pointers in all possible ways I know (I dont't know if some or all of them are wrong).
Error message which I got while compilation has been put as a comment in front of that line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not dealing with a function pointer, you're dealing with a pointer-to-member-funciton. These are very different beasts. Think of the latter as "identifier of function within an object." You must use it with an object to get something callable. In other words, this:

```
bool B::m_process(A* A_ptr)
{
    m_add_ptr = A_ptr->add_ptr;
    (A_ptr->*m_add_ptr)(2, 3);
}
```

`->*` (and corresponding `.*`) is the operator for dereferencing pointers-to-member.